# how to export all FreeIPA users list to a csv format?

Tags: linux, redhat, ldap, freeipa

How can export all FreeIPA users to a csv file?

Comment: none that I know of, but quite simple to roll your own with some basic scripting.

Comment: indeed, two minutes with a shell in a host with the ipa-admin tools installed: ipa user-find | grep login | awk ' {print $NF}' | awk '{printf "%s,",$0} END {print ""}' and I get a comma separated listi of user names. Dumping this to a file and retrieving more than 100 records will be left as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: but using Apache Directory Studio (a ldap browser) you can do just that, Select the part of the tree you need, and export it to csv, it works

Comment: @natxoasenjo Thanks for your update. I tried same way but I am missing something. I want show in like First Name, Last Name, Email, Mobile. format.

Comment: if you try with-   ipa user-find --all  |  grep -E  "First|Last|Email"  you will get result like.  
  First name: test1
  Last name: test2
  Email address: test21@ipa.example.com
 this need to be in CSV format

Comment: the easiest without scripting it yourself would be to use Apache Directory Studio, you can specify what attributes you want to export

Answer (score 6):

This command worked for me:

```
ipa user-find --all | grep -E "User Login|First|Last|UID|Email" > IPA_RAW.txt
```

after that, use this perl line to convert the format:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; print $_ . (($. % 8) ? "," : "\n")' IPA_RAW.txt | awk "Add your filters here" > users-list.csv
```

thanks

Comment: If you have a lot of records returned you will need to first modify the limit or the results will be truncated. `ipa config-mod --searchrecordslimit=######`

Comment: I like that this uses IPA and perl without needing to add other items.  I think I will use sed to convert, since I don't know perl.

Comment: You can also dynamically change the number of records if it exceeds the default (600) by including the `--sizelimit=XXX` when running any `ipa user-find ...` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Late but full "copy/paste" answer (based on previous ones - thanks -  I could have quit after writing ipa2json); for present and future needs.

Export users with:

```
ipa user-find --all > ipa.txt
```

If the output is truncated adjust the limit with the command below and retry:

```
ipa config-mod --searchrecordslimit=######
```

To use this method you need nodejs on the machine (or container) where you intend to process ipa.txt; for this I suggest using nvm:

```
# install nodejs version manager (nvm) for the current user (not root!)
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash

# install the latest nodejs long time support (lts) version for the current user
nvm install --lts
```

Install the required scripts as command line tools for the current user:

```
npm i -g ipa2json      # to convert ipa output to json
npm i -g equalizejson  # to spread missing fields in every record
npm i -g json2csv      # to convert the json to csv
```

Convert ipa output to json with:

```
ipa2json ipa.txt > ipa.json
```

Equalize the json (you need all the fields in all the instances for proper csv conversion) and convert to csv :

```
equalizejson ipa.json | json2csv > ipa.csv
```

To uninstall nvm, nodejs and the scripts you may just remove the `$NVM_DIR` folder (usually `~/.nvm`), as documented when you type "nvm" in the terminal.

Comment: i suggest, you should explain what kind of script you plan to install, and why we should install it?

Comment: @djdomi If you need answers about some script you consider to install, please be more specific, But first please read the description with "npm info" or on the related github page if the script name is not sufficient to picture it. As for why you should install it, obviously to achieve the expected result.

Comment: @LucDeschenaux, they're referring to the github script (from a random project from an unknown account) suggested in the answer.  There is no information about the script.  Due dilligence would be to go to github and look at what the script does.

Comment: @Jeter-work Good, do look at what the script does despite of anybody says. Or if it is not applicable, run it in a container or a VM without internet access instead, that's best practice.